# problem with couchdb remote replication: ubuntu (local) CentOS ( remote )

Tags: security, replication, couchdb

trying to replicate a couchdb between my local machine and a remote server. 
For some weird reason the replication fails with the error message:

"Replication failed: {bad_term,<0.12494.1>}."

Actually a part of the documents are imported successfully, namely around 300. The live db holds around 1500 documents.

We debugged this process and we concluded the couchdb replication has a throughput of 1 doc per second.

The problem is that we cannot replicate the remote db to my local machine.

Is there anyone with a similar problem? Any solutions here?

What can the problem be?

THanks in advance,

Christian de vilder.

Answer (score 2):

I asked in `#couchdb` in freenode, and fdmanana says both the slowdown and the error have been fixed in couchdb 1.0.2:

```
<fdmanana> Chipaca, the the issues described there are fixed for 1.0.2
<fdmanana> (both the error in the log and the slowdown)
<Chipaca> fdmanana: do you have a bug number? :)
<fdmanana> Chipaca, for the slowdown:  COUCHDB-992
<fdmanana> Chipaca, for the error at the end:  COUCHDB-993
```

Comment: so if i get it right i should wait for this release? its not yet available for dl on the apache site

Comment: it's already tagged, so you should be seeing it very soon. Or you can grab it off SVN: `svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/couchdb/tags/1.0.2 couchdb-1.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty trick to help solve replication errors. Take advantage of the cloud.

### Reproduce the replication error on a CouchDB hosting provider and then blame them for it

They will either find the bug and fix it; or they will prove to you they're not responsible by troubleshooting your issue.

Posting on a public forum like Stack Overflow or Get Satisfaction is ideal.